# Hide kendo ui upload's message after upload a picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I wonder if there is a way to hide the loading message after loading a picture with the "kendo-ui-uploader". Strangely, with the previous version, this "big message" did not appear; however, with this new version, I really see no reason to change the previous loading message as it was smaller and better,  this huge message appears. In addition, its styles cannot be changed manually because the view is ruined

**This is how it look like before uploading**

[image: This is how it look like before uploading]

**This is how it look like after uploading**

[image]

I hope someone knows something about it.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To hide the "Done" message, you might try specifying the Blank string

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="photos" />
<script>
$("#photos").kendoUpload({

    localization: {
        statusUploaded: ""
    }
});
```

Look at the documentation of the Upload control [Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/upload) says you can specify your own template your you can have custom messages.

You can use the following code to customize the message

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="photos" />
<script>
$("#photos").kendoUpload({

    localization: {
        statusUploading: "Loading Your Language"
    }
});
```

Or you can define custom template, it doesn't look like custom template has enough to offer; alternatively you can try the jQuery selector hacks to hide the message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I just do not want to change the filelist. What I want to change or to hide(if it posible) the 'done' message which is shown after an upload.

Comment: Sorry my friend but I try what you add to your answer and I does not work. This message is annoying me. u.u

Answer (score 1):

//put it when  kendo contol is loaded (in javascript) it hides done message

```
        var upload = $("#files").data("kendoUpload");

       $.extend(upload.options.localization, {
            headerStatusUploading: "",
            headerStatusUploaded: ""
        });
```

//in upload call back hide comment icon

$(".k-icon.k-warning").hide();

Answer (score -1):

This answer does not work I am sorry to say...

DOES NOT WORK:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="photos" />
<script>
$("#photos").kendoUpload({

    localization: {
        statusUploading: "Loading Your Language"
    }
});
```

However if you look at the documentation, it looks like the answer was almost correct, just had to wrong property. It should be...

DOES WORK:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="photos" />
<script>
$("#photos").kendoUpload({

    localization: {
        headerStatusUploaded: "Loading Your Language"
    }
});
```

This makes it so you do not see the Done text.  Keep in mind, however, that this does not remove the checkmark. Hope this helps someone.